# docker exec. What if there is no shell process?

Tags: docker

`docker exec <container> <command>`. 
In the documentation it is written:

> Run a command in a running container

But what does it mean exactly? What does it mean to execute a command in container. I can't imagine a situation that `exec` command is executed by a shell run in the container. But we cannot assume that every container has run shell or shell at whole.

Comment: if you use `FROM alpine` in your Dockerfile, you will have /bin/sh, but of course, you can't be sure that `docker exec -it container_id_or_name myprogram` will find myprogram inside

Comment: Yes, but what if I use `FROM sth` where `sth` doesn't has sh?

Comment: you have to install it, if you want to use bash in an Alpine container, you need to install it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `docker exec <container> <command>` will run given command in the namespaces of the specified container. The docker exec creates new process and sets its namespaces to container's namespaces and after that executes command.

More on Linux namespaces can be found here:
[Namespaces in operation](https://lwn.net/Articles/531114/)

Namespaces of a process can be found using the following command:

`sudo ls -l /proc/<PID>/ns`

Comment: Thanks! You answered my question.

Answer (score 0):

A container is an isolated environment for your process, with its own network environment, mounted filesystems, namespaced process list, etc. When you perform a `docker run` you create this namespace by running a command as pid 1. When you perform a `docker exec` you can run any command inside this same namespace. E.g.:

```
$ docker run --name test-exec -d busybox tail -f /dev/null
5e77cec13293e7146dac6858ed11be1e6a706ba973c419435303f4ec8c346e2d

$ docker exec test-exec ps -ef
PID   USER     TIME   COMMAND
    1 root       0:00 tail -f /dev/null
    6 root       0:00 ps -ef
```

Note that in neither of the above commands did I even run a shell.

Comment: "namespaced process". Thanks for pointing it. Can you refer me to any Unix book to read about it? 

"Note that in neither of the above commands did I even run a shell." Yes, you are right. So, I understand that it called tail from `/usr/bin` or `/bin`. Hmm, I think that I have to read about namespaces in Unix to grasp it more deeply.

Comment: Don't know about a book, but this link from docker may help: https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/security/